# How to fix System.TypeInitializationException: runtime error?

Tags: c#, xamarin, google-api

Once I put API access restriction with SHA-1 signing-certificate, there is TypeInitializationException error thrown. If I remove the API access restriction, I can get the Json return back and there is no run-time error. So the following is where I assign the data.

```
public class DataFactory
{
    public static IList<Video> Videos { get; private set; }  

    static DataFactory()
    {
        Videos = new ObservableCollection<Video> { };
```

Comment: Most commonly, a TypeInitializationException exception is thrown when a static constructor is unable to instantiate a type. The InnerException property indicates why the static constructor was unable to instantiate the type.You can refer to the Microsoft Docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.typeinitializationexception?view=netframework-4.7.2#static-constructors-and-the-typeinitializationexception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found out what went wrong.

When I have a restriction to access the Google API, I didn't have the necessary headers info such as Package Name or SHA1 key.

And so there is that runtime error. And I didn't have the exception handling for that.